# DOM structure in Scrapy is different from what's in a browser

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to learn scraping web content with Scrapy and came across an issue that I'm unable to comprehend. I can't understand why it's happening; I'm able to select a DOM element with any browser's dev tools, but when I try to select the very same element from **Scrapy** an empty list is returned. Here you can see that this **xpath** `//*[@class='lSPager lSGallery']/li/a/img[@src]` works fine in a browser [image] , but returns nothing when it's called from **Scrapy**: [image: empty string returned from scrapy]
Moreover **Scrapy** completely doesn't see the `lSPager` class 
[image]
 which can be easily selected in a browser [image] [image]

Answer (score 1):

OK, I figured it out just right after I wrote the question. The problem was that I had JavaScript enabled in the browser. I disabled JS and DOM structure in the browser became the same as in the Scrapy.